# Replace all occurence in qml string

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to replace all occurrences of line breaks to html line breaks in my string, but it is only converting the  first one found

```
var output= "";
string x = "Hi\nMy name is x\nAnd age is 10\n";
output = x
output = output.replace("\\n", "<br>")
```

Output =

```
Hi
My name is x\nAnd age is 10\n
```

Comment: Output doesn't contains `<br>`...

Comment: @MarekR This is qml

Comment: @Jarod42 Output first line break was replaced correctly. Obviously I mean output to screen not the output string itself

Comment: `string::replace` != `QString::replace`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am actually using the [text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#text-prop), so it is a string

Comment: [Doc says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-string.html): `QML extends the JavaScript String type with a arg() function to support value substitution.`, So [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: @tester123 Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript, use `output = output.replace(new RegExp("\\n", 'g'), "<br>")`

Comment: @eyllanesc: If you make this an answer, I can award my bounty to it. Otherwise it will just expire. Also, is QML strictly equivalent to ECMA script? Otherwise I would not consider this to be a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html: *Like a browser or server-side JavaScript environment, the QML runtime implements the ECMAScript Language Specification standard. This provides access to all of the built-in types and functions defined by the standard, such as Object, Array, and Math. The QML runtime implements the 7th edition of the standard.*

Answer (score 3):

QML is just a very feeble front end to JavaScript. You need to use the JavaScript global option.

```
str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
```

In your case that would be:

```
output = output.replace("\\n/g", "<br>")
```